# PHP- Pull HTML Source Code for parsing

Tags: php

I would like to to pull the source code using file('http://finance.yahoo.com/quote/VASIX/performance?p=VASIX');

If I visit that page via browser the web page with the data in the table 'Annual Total Return (%) History' Shows all the years and corresponding loss or gain percentage however when viewing source code that data isn't in there. I can find it in the Chrome inspect element feature but I would like to pull it with PHP so I can parse it.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

TIA

Comment: Please explain your answer a bit more. not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Maybe Yahoo wants to protect their sources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The website is using ajax call to another url to append the contents to the page. One way to find the API url is by monitoring the network activity.

Open Chrome Developer Tools > Network. Reload the page, and monitor the network activity in the XHR tab.

Edit:
Here is what I found in the network activity. Take a look at the "annualTotalReturns" array

https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/VASIX?formatted=true&crumb=KqFrauIpged&lang=en-US&region=US&modules=assetProfile%2CfundPerformance%2CtopHoldings%2CdefaultKeyStatistics&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com

Comment: That works great! I'm able to get the source and do what I need. But I can't figure out how you found that. Is there as text search tool in that Development window?

Comment: Great. Just open up the developer tools in google chrome by pressing F12, and then Click on the "Network" tab, beside the "Console" tab.

After that, you will see text like this: All | XHR JS CSS...
just click on the XHR.
Finally reload the page, and check each link in the box. Read here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/resource-loading?utm_source=dcc&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=2016q3

Comment: Please mark my answer as the answer if you found it useful :)